# logout causes Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react native app and I have a logout button which I use `AuthContext` like in the following:

```
import React from "react";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
```

and in another screen where I have the logout like this:

```
const { signOut } = React.useContext(AuthContext);


 <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={async () => {
        await signOut();
     }}
     >
     <Text>logout</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

when I press logout sometimes I get this error:
seems like everytime the error is different!

[image]
[image]

sometimes it doesnt happen, I am not quit sure what to do about it.

Comment: Could you attach larger snippet of your code? I can see `password2InputChange` being listed in stack trace. This warning is probably related to it.

Comment: @Aitwar that code is in  another screen for registering so I do see why they should be relevant!

Comment: You see - there may be some asynchronous action executed which resolves just after you sign out therefore it tries to call `setState` when component is no longer mounted.